# Executar JavaScript ao atualizar a pagina

Tags: javascript, script

Tenho uma aplicação html5, com uma unica função JavaScript, que mantem o scroll sempre no final da pagina, neste HTML, tenho uma tag de atualização onde posso definir o tempo de atualização automática, esta pagina vai carregar um arquivo de texto txt que é atualizado por uma fonte externa a cada 10 segundos, gostaria de saber se é possível executar um script sempre que a pagina for atualizada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tente isto:

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1000);
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 1000);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "arquivo.txt", true);
    xhttp.responseType = "text";
    xhttp.onreadystatecange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState ==4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var conteúdo = xhttp.responseText;
            var resposta = xhttp.response;
            document.writeln("variável conteúdo: " + conteúdo);

            document.writeln("variável resposta: " + resposta);
        }
    };
    xhttp.onerror = function() {
        document.writeln("<H1>Error HTTP_ERROR_" + xhttp.status + " bad request.</H1>"); // Se der erro, ele vai mostrar um aviso tipo 404...
    };
};
```

***Este código não funciona em arquivos locais, apenas em no WebServer.***

Comment: Para evitar longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89876/discussion-on-answer-by-eduapps-executa-script-ao-atualizar-a-pagina), para prosseguir basta clicar no link